# Ctrl-Shift-M no longer working in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008

I find it useful and productive to use the built in <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> when creating a new stored proc in SQL Server Management Studio (2008). On one of my machines that keyboard shortcut combo has stopped working and I've been unable to work out how to restore it.

There could also be some new utility on my machine that's overriding that but I have been unable to find culprit if that's the case.

Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion from Rob yet? I'm interested to know the results.

Comment: You can edit the template so that it displays the Alt-Q, S combo rather than the deprecated one: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/19887/specify-values-for-template-parameters-command

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This keyboard combination has been removed from SQL 2008.  You can still get to the functionality by selecting Query >> Specify Values for Template Parameters...

This is quite confusing because most templates still reference the keyboard combo.  (The menu item above even references it!!)

Unfortunately, we can't "restore" the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>M</kbd> command.  SQL Mgmt Studio doesn't allow adding new shortcuts.  Only "query" shortcuts (Options >> Environment >> Keyboard).

The easiest way to resolve this is to just learn the new keyboard sequence:  <kbd>Alt</kbd> >> <kbd>Q</kbd> >> <kbd>S</kbd>

Here's a confirmation by Mark Han on the MS Online Community Support team:

> In order to resolve the issue, I
>   would like to explain the following 
>         A) I have re-produce the issue and compare it with SQL Server 2005
>            Management Studio. It is confirmed that the "Ctrl-Shift-M "
>   shortcut key
>            does not exist in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio. If you have
>   concerns
>            on that, please send us a feedback via the
>            address(https://connect.microsoft.com/sql).
>   Besides I'm consulting with our
>            dev team with the issue; if anything updates, we will public[ize] it. 
>         B) Ctrl-Shift-M is used to replace template parameters, we  also
>   can open
>             Specify Values for Template Parameters manually 
>             1) On the Query menu, click Specify Values for Template
>   Parameters. 
>             2) In the Specify Values for Template Parameters dialog box, the
>                Values column contains suggested value for the
>                parameter (Database Name in the example above). Accept the
>   value
>                or replace it with a new value, and then click OK
>                to close the Replace Template Parameters dialog box and
>   modify
>                the script in the query editor.

Hope this helped!

Comment: Just use Autohotkey and remap Control-Shift-M to Alt-Q-S

Comment: In SSMS 2012 You can certainly re-assign the Ctrl Shift M keyboard shortcut (not used in 2012) back to `Query.SpecifyValuesForTemplateParamters`.

Comment: You can also edit the `Create Stored Procedure (New Menu).sql` file in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql\Stored Procedure` to reference `Alt + Q + S` instead of `Ctrl + Shift + M`, that way you'll learn the new keyboard shortcut easily

Answer (score 3):

In SSMS click on Tools on the menu bar and select the Options menu item.

When the Options form opens...
1.) Select Keyboard in the left pane.

2.) On the right pane change the "Apply the following additional keyboard mapping scheme:" drop down list to "Visual Studio 2010 Compatible."

3.) Click on the OK button to save the changes and close the Options form.

Now when you select the Query menu on the menu bar it should display Ctrl+Shift+M as the shortcut next to the Specify Values for Template Parameters menu item.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely sounds like you have something else that is stealing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, just like how I lose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> (to run sp_help) when I'm running ZoomIt.

You could try running Task Manager, and then see what moves when you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>.

But there may be an option to make SSMS react to it again... I'll try looking when I've finished reinstalling SQL 2008 (after a Win7 rebuild)

Comment: It works fine for me (Vista/SQL2008), so I'd second that something is stealing it.